# Disabled input - what can be the cause?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, error-handling, monitoring

Today, during casual checking of our delivery adress forms, I have encountered for the first time a weird issue. Phone number (a required input field) was unclickable, so I couldn't move on with the form to finalize an order. I managed to replicate this issue using Opera and Chrome, but only twice.

Refreshing, moving back and forth did not remove the error. When I used a radio button to switch from cell to landline, it became active again. Other input fields were working fine.

What can be the cause of such error? I never realized something as this exists, how can I prevent it or monitor for it?

This basically prevents our clients from completing their order, so it's a big red flag.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons.  Unless you can give us code to reproduce the issue then we're in the dark and you'll get guesses, a lot of which will be from people that have only read a few words of the question.

Comment: IS there a URL we can look at? Impossible to help otherwise.

Comment: I expected this answer, unfortunately this was such a big red flag for me that I instantly tried to replicate it among other browsers and forgot to copy the code / network log :(